# Tensorflow not found. pip 21.3.1, Python 3.8.9

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install TF but pip is failing to find any of it's versions.

`pip install tensorflow` returns

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

and
`pip show tensorflow` says

```
WARNING: Package(s) not found: tensorflow
```

I am using macOS with an m1 pro chip, can that be related to the issue in some way?

Comment: if you check the [tensorflow pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files), you will see only files for mac x86_64, nothing for the m1 yet

Comment: After re-installing python with `arch -x86_64` it started to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

you may also need:

```
brew install hdf5
export HDF5_DIR=$(brew --prefix hdf5)
```